# Sharedpreference is not saving

Tags: android, eclipse, boolean, sharedpreferences

i have a problem with my sharedpreferences, it is not working.

I have strugled with this, for very long now and i'm so frustrated why this won't work.

I have tried to put the load method in the Oncreate and also in the Onresume method none of them have worked.

I want to save my:

boolean value = stopValue, this should be false the first time i use the app, and in the future it should load from what have been saved last. The boolean value change when i use buttons in another class, therefore i have the getIntent().getBooleanExtra();

String, called date.

An Int, startkilometer.

These are the data to be stored.

Thanks for your time.

But here is my code for my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

Button bStart, bStop;
TextView tvView;
Spinner spinner1;
boolean stopValue;
int startkilometer;
String date;
SharedPreferences prefs;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);







    date = getIntent().getStringExtra("datoen");
    startkilometer = getIntent().getIntExtra("startkm", startkilometer);
    stopValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stopper", stopValue);


    if(stopValue == false){
        bStart.setText("Start");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent start = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.START");
                startActivity(start);
            }
        });
    }

    if(stopValue){
        bStart.setText("Stop");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent stop = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.STOP");
                stop.putExtra("startkm", startkilometer);
                stop.putExtra("datoen", date);
                startActivity(stop);
            }
        });
    }

    KilometerSQL info = new KilometerSQL(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tvView.setText(data);

    }




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onResume();       

prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

prefs.getBoolean("stopper", false);
prefs.getInt("startkm", startkilometer);
prefs.getString("datoen", date);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("stopper", stopValue);
    edit.putInt("startkm", startkilometer);
    edit.putString("datoen", date);
    edit.commit();

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what r u trying to do

Comment: what I can assure you it's not how you read and right on sharedprefs. it's something in the app logic.

Comment: im trying to save the 3 values, but it doesn't work.. It won't save..

Comment: Okay, by that you mean my keys and def values or the logic by the voolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialise the prefs variable in every method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("stopper", stopValue);
    edit.putInt("startkm", startkilometer);
    edit.putString("datoen", date);
    edit.commit();
```

following lines is useless. values not taken. how do you take values?

```
prefs.getBoolean("stopper", false);
prefs.getInt("startkm", startkilometer);
prefs.getString("datoen", date);
```

Comment: The one who helped me with this told me to use that for loading things. I asked earlier in another question, because i had another mistake, and he told me to rewrite all my codes, in a way i didn't understand, so i closed my eyes and followed his commands. Are my "loading" method not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
 .edit()
 .putBoolean("stopper", stopValue)
 .putInt(etc)
 .commit()
```